# Write video in Python at 60 frames per second

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, scikits

I would like to use Python to create a video file with 60 frames per second.

I try to make a two-minute video (`DURATION_SECONDS = 120`) as follows, but I get a video that lasts for 4 minutes and 48 seconds instead of 2 minutes. So the frame rate seems to be 25, even though I pass 60 to `FFmpegWriter`. What am I doing wrong?

```py
FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60
DURATION_SECONDS = 120

import skvideo
skvideo.setFFmpegPath('C:\\ffmpeg\\x64')
import skvideo.io
import numpy as np

video_writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter("test.mp4", outputdict={'-r':str(FRAMES_PER_SECOND)})

for i in range(DURATION_SECONDS*FRAMES_PER_SECOND):
    video_writer.writeFrame(np.zeros((100,100)))
    
video_writer.close()
```

I get the same result also with
`outputdict={'-vf':f"fps={FRAMES_PER_SECOND}"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is passing `inputdict={'-framerate':str(FRAMES_PER_SECOND)}` to `FFmpegWriter` instead of `outputdict` with `-r`.

Neither `inputdict` nor `outputdict` are documented in `skvideo` (no mention of `ffmpeg` documentation, no examples), nor is `-framerate` properly documented in [the `ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) (it speaks about grabbing rather than saving, and claims that the default is `30000/1001` even though it is `25`), nor is `-framerate` even mentioned when calling `ffmpeg --help`.

Shout out to @Goury for not deleting [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66466897/5231110) (which helped here a lot) despite having received a negative score of -3 from the StackOverflow community in that thread.